# I am trying to call this API using jQuery and I have included proper cdn but it is showing "$ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to call this API but it is not working and giving the error of $ is not defined. I have used the proper API token ad included the jquery CDN in the HTML. Here is the code of both HTML and JS.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var hbs = require('hbs');

app.set('view-engine', 'hbs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    $.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': 'my api token' },
    url: 'https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
       }).done(function(response) {
        // do something with the response, e.g. isolate the id of a linked resource   
        res.send(response);
       });
})



app.listen(3000);
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256- 
WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

The error I am getting is  "$ is not defined".

Comment: You've mixed up front end and back end. AJAX would typically be a part of your front end  which sends request to a server like express

Comment: That first piece of code is node code, running on the server-side. To make requests from there, you need to use node's `http` module, or a similar solution.

Comment: even after including it in my HTML as script it still shows $ is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing back-end and front-end code here. Also on the front-end you are including two different jQuery versions.

I would recommend changing your front-end code to something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
<script>
  $.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': 'my api token' },
    url: 'https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
  }).done(function(response) {
    // do something with the response
    console.log(response);
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can I not make the ajax request from a separate js file? I tried it there is the reference error

Comment: Sure, you just need to include that JS file after you include jQuery and there should not be a problem.